# Can a java thread (defined in a method) be suspended from another method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread defined in a method. Like this:

```
public void startTimer(){
    Thread timer=new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            //do something
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

I want to create another method :

```
public void stopTimer(){
    //this method will suspend the thread named timer
}
```

What will be the code for **stopTimer()** definition?

Comment: There is no safe way to do this.  See [Java Thread Primitive Deprecation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

Comment: In future please pay attention to the potential duplicates the question entry form brings up.  Don't ask blatantly duplicate questions.